# Trying to open by VBA a ".docx" word document based on a ".dotm" template will launch a temporary file with security message even in trusted folder

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, ms-word, office365

Sorry I asked the same question in an [Access World post](https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/threads/second-instance-of-word-opened-from-access-arises-security-warning.329531/#post-1898876), but I could not found a solution.

In an Access form or in an Excel userform, I have a text box and a button. In the text box the user will insert the full name of a Word ".docx" document, based on a Word ".dotm" template; the button will open the Word Document.
The template has only two macros in `Document_New` and `Dcument_Open` (`Debug.Print Now()`).
The documents, the template, and the mother application are all in a trusted folder.
The code to open the file is the following:

```vb
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   Dim objWordApp As Word.Application
   Dim sFileName As String
     
   sFileName = Me.TextBox1
   On Error Resume Next
   Set objWordApp = GetObject("Word.Application")
   If Err.Number <> 0 Then Set objWordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
   On Error GoTo 0
   With objWordApp
       .Visible = True
       .Activate
       .Documents.Open sFileName
   End With
End Sub
```

When a first file is opened in this way everything is fine. When I try to open a second one the following security warning pops up:
[image]

A little more information.

If the files are based on "normal.dotm" no problem.

I used similar code tons of times in the past without problems.
Now I'm having this problem with a desktop Windows 11 Pro Build 22631.2715 and Word Microsoft 365 Version 2310 (build 16924.20150).

When I debug the code in the mother app and using Windows Task Manager I can see that:

- the `sFileName` is correct, the first and the second time.
- if I push on the "Disable macros" button in the notice, the right file, with the right name, is opened.
- one instance of Word is correctly in WTManager, just before the second time
- the second time, the opened instance of Word is never found (`GetObject("Word.Application")`)
- the second time, in the WTManager I found the second instance of Word but without file name.

When testing same files, same "*.dotm" on my laptop with Windows 10 Home Build 19045.3570 and Word Microsoft 365 Version 2309 (build 16827.20166). And I had this even stranger behavior on the second file

- In the Windows Task Manager, I found the expected instance of Word, but 2 more instances both with a security warning that links to THE NEFARIOUS POP UP MESSAGE.
- If I ignore the Windows Task Manager and I continue to debug the code in Excel when I reach the instruction `.Visible = True` it trows the error.

I don't know what to think.
Do you have any suggestions.

Comment: What is the significance of the template if the user opens an already existing document created from that template? The macros are in the document, so a warning should appear.

Comment: I am not sure if the error is related with GetObject. But it should be `GetObject(,"Word.Application")` . _Microsoft documentation:_

> [GetObject function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: The macros are in the template on which the document are based. If the document are saved in trusted folder no warning should appears.

Comment: Thank you taller! You correctly spotted the error in my code. That was the reason why the already opened instance of Word was never found!

Comment: Still I don't understand why opening several instances of Word should create the security problem!